# jquery effect is not smooth in phonegap iphone

Tags: jquery, cordova

jquery effect is not smooth in phonegap application on iphone

i am using simple script for show-hide but page is blinking up.

```
/* enter code here */
$( '#signupbtn1' ).live('click',function(event)
    {
       $('#header').slideUp('slow');
       $('#content').slideDown('slow');
});
```

any idea why it's not working properly

Comment: Not sure, but you should use .on instead of .live as that is now being phased out

Comment: sorry brother, .on isn't working.. :(

Comment: No that wasnt to fix the problem, i was just saying you should use .on instead of .live from now on.

Comment: how .on will improve performance compare to .live :) ?

Comment: It isn't simply about a performance boost, .live is now deprecated and unless you are using an old version of jQuery you should use .on() instead. That said, you will indeed see a performance increase using .on() due to being able to delegate from a more specific element. Using .live() the event is bound to <body> meaning every single click on the page will have to be checked  for #signupbtn1, if you delegate it to something further down the DOM hierarchy (some static wrapper above #signupbtn1) it will only check clicks within that element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [jquery.animte-enhanced](http://playground.benbarnett.net/jquery-animate-enhanced/) plugin? It speed up animation by detecting browser support for CSS3 animations. On iOS, using `translate3d` to animate some element is extremely  fast, cause it is benefited from GPU acceleration. I used to write some animation library only relying on CSS3 animation, it's a wonderful experience on iOS. But Android would drive you crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Similar thing happened to me before. I was trying to animate the last menu item on the right side(a search box like Apple has) and everything was blinking.
What I did was changing `float:right`to`position:absolute;right:0;` in the css of the specific item and added `position:relative;` to the container of the animation.

Hopefully the trick will work for you too! Just edit the positioning to fit your needs, but if you want something to slide in/slide out properly and stay in the same place, positioning should more than likely do the trick.

Using .on instead of live is advised by jQuery, as live is deprecated and event delegation is now handled in a very different way.

Answer (score 0):

I know this response is years after you originally asked this question, however your question is one of the few listed when googling for help regarding this.

So here is a solution from blog of Chrissilich [Blog](http://chrissilich.com/blog/), solution is here [solution to fix choppy animations](http://chrissilich.com/blog/fix-css-animation-slow-or-choppy-in-mobile-browsers/)

Basically, he advises adding the following `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` to the element your are trying to animate.

It worked beautifully for me like it did for many others.